# Is there a way to safely accept payments on a Facebook Messenger chatbot?

Tags: botframework, chatbot, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I have a customer that wants to create a chatbot da allows their customers to buy their products via a Facebook Messenger chatbot. I'm using the Microsoft Bot Framework, and so far I haven't been able to think of a way to do this in a safe manner.

The customer wants the bot to ask the customer for credit card information, but I know that's horrible idea when you think about safety. The customer credit card information will be stored on the Facebook Messenger history as plain text, which will impose a great threat if the user account gets compromised.

Also the chatbot administrator will have access to all of that information, making possible for an employee to take advantage of that information. I'm well aware that this is a terrible idea, and I'll do my best to explain why.

However I would like to know if there's a safe way to allow users to perform these kind of operations, buying products and services via chatbot applications while on Facebook Messenger (or maybe even via other channels).

The first thing that comes to mind is to allow the user to choose products and services via the chatbot application and them provide him to a link where he can finish the transaction in a safely manner. However because the user is leaving the chatbot ecosystem (which is not great) I feel like this alternative might be rejected.

Is there a way to accomplish this in a safe manner?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/payments#payment_providers is what you're looking for!

Comment: @JJ_Wailes It seems like all the payment providers are available for U.S.-based transactions only, and I'm based in South America. So it seems like there's no option. :/

Comment: Your best bet is probably to do the transaction on a web page by redirecting with an OpenURL button if none of the payment processing options facebook offers work for you.

Answer (score 1):

As @JasonSowers mentioned, you can direct the user to any online payment flow using the URL button to open the webview. One caveat is you must apply to offer payments outside of the Messenger client with this form:

https://www.facebook.com/help/contact/919889051467941